# MySQL uses half cores of my server

Tags: mysql, cpu, gentoo

I'm running MySQL 5.1.62 on a 64-bits Gentoo Box.

This MySQL is heavy loaded but the problem is that it uses only half the cores of the server :

> Cpu0  : 84.0%us, 13.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  3.0%si,  0.0%st
>
> Cpu1  : 62.4%us, 34.7%sy,  0.0%ni,  3.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
>
> Cpu2  : 68.3%us, 26.7%sy,  0.0%ni,  5.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
>
> Cpu3  : 72.3%us,  3.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 22.8%id,  2.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
>
> Cpu4  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
>
> Cpu5  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
>
> Cpu6  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
>
> Cpu7  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

This is a Dual-Quad core server with : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5606  @ 2.13GHz

Any idea how to use all cores?

Thanks for your help;

Gaëtan

Comment: Are you sure mysql can actually use more than 4 threads? Check this page, there are interesting informations: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-threads.html

Comment: As far as I read on that page yes it can, but still did you observe one day a CORE (i.e. not counting the connections threads and so.) mysql using more than 4 threads? How many did you see? (for my personnal culture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of MySQL or the [Percona](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-server/) enhanced MySQL server may make better use of your cores.  It's fairly common for database servers to be IO bound, though.

Comment: Actually, I've noticed that, when changing some table from MyISAM to InnoDB, it uses much more cores than usual.
I'll try to look at :

#innodb_file_io_threads = 4

#innodb_thread_concurrency = 8

To make it run smooth. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Idea? Yep, but you won't like it.

Many cores do not automagically make a system faster: The workload it runs need to be easily parallelizable.

What I suspect to happen in your case is, that you are running a small number of concurrent queries, each being CPU intensive. As it happens, each will only use a single core.

To check, if this is the culprit, manually start 8 concurrent, CPU-Intensive queries - your CPUs should be fully used.

Comment: Actually, yes. If I run something else (such as emerge), it uses the remaining cores.